# (Mysql)only shows credit is more than 0 after calculation

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql database which is about accounting, I could like to display the invoice no. which still in credit.

```
inv no. credit debit
001     5000   1000
002     2000   2000
003    10000      0
004     5000    100
005     3500   3500
```

the answer should be

```
inv no. credit debit Bal
001     5000   1000  4000
003    10000      0  10000
004     5000    100  4900
```

I have try the following code, but it shows the invoice which settled already as well

```
SELECT *
     , SUM(credit - debit) AS 'Bal' 
  FROM payable
 WHERE 'bal' = 0 
 GROUP 
    BY `inv no.`
```

anyone know the answer?

Comment: How do you know if an invoice is settled or not?

Comment: 'bal' is a string. And including spaces, punctuation, and/or mathematical operators within table/column identifiers is a catclysmically bad idea.

Comment: And in a GROUP BY query, `SELECT *` is never going to make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its as simple as that:

```
SELECT t.* FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.credit - t.debit > 0
```

If you do have multiple records with the same invoice number, then this will work:

```
SELECT s.* FROM 
(SELECT t.invNo, sum(t.credit) as credit, sum(t.debit) as debit FROM YourTable t
group by t.invNo) s
WHERE s.credit-s.debit > 0
```